Why is openSUSE TW complaining can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct?
I recently noticed that every console applications is griping about my locale settings.  I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed x86_64.
 09:39 ~ $  locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME=en_ZA.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_VI.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

I had set LC_MEASUREMENT and LC_TIME so I get metric system (which the US adopted back in 1866, and is routinely used in medicine, science, and the military) and time done YYYY/MM/DD (which, IMHO, is the only sensible way). Furthermore, I have used these settings for a long time, and don't recall ever seeing issues with them in the past, but now every time I look up something I get apropos: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct or
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_VI.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "en_ZA.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").

If I set LC_ALL to en_US.UTF-8, it shuts everything up, but then my time and units get obliterated.  My understanding is that LC_ALL just stomps all over all other settings, which makes it less useful to have the other settings.
Besides convincing my fellow citizens that we should abandon the archaic imperial measurement system and our odd ordering of date elements, what can I do to convince my computer that I really want to use metric units and ISO-8601/rfc-3339 conventions for dates?  I do as much as I can with aliases (e.g. alias ls='ls -AFlh --color=auto --group-directories-first --time-style=long-iso' but using an alias w/ date often screws up scripts) and KDE Plasma 6 now liberates users from C-language locale settings, so it isn't the end of the world, but still, I am missing something here...

We will need your /etc/locale.gen

Try running sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales (link).
